# cypress upload to github does node_modules needed?

Tags: github, cypress

does "node_modules" folder required when I upload the cypress folders to github?

i am very new to this and wonder if my teammate can run the test at his machine without downloading the "node_modules".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a file called `.gitignore` and mention `node_modules` there. Then when you are uploading your project to GitHub, everything that is mentioned in .gitignore would be ignored for upload. It is not advised to upload the `node_modules` folder to git. This is how my gitignore looks like for my project:

[image: git ignore]

Now if your teammate wants to execute the test, they can just run the command `npm install`. It will install download all the dependencies from the `package.json` file and will automatically create a `node_modules` folder in their machine.

Comment: Looks beautiful!